# Oldest Garuda Purana manuscript?

Tags: manuscripts, garuda-purana

How many versions of Garuda Purana are available ?

From which manuscript, the present form of Garuda Purana is printed ?

How many manuscripts are there?

Comment: Hello, please edit the question for more clarity. Although all the questions are related, please focus on a single question. Whether you are interested in count or the age of the scripture etc., should be clear.